# String.Format inside of array

Tags: c#, string.format

So I have the string format split into two arrays:

String:

```
{ "{0}", "hit", "{1}" }
```

Values:

```
{ "Player", "Enemy" }
```

is there a way to format this ? Can I still use String.Format?

EDIT:

I believe that I have not described the issue well:

The expected result would be new array or the first array edited like:

```
{ "Player" , "hit" , "Enemy" }
```

Please keep in mind that value "Enemy" can also be "Enemy 1" or "Enemy Strong" etc.

Comment: No. What is the first array supposed to represent? Why isn't it `"{0} hit {1}"`? You can join the first array using a space to create such a format string, if that's what you mean...

Comment: Is the string really: `string text = "{ \"{0}\", \"hit\", \"{1}\" }"`?

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: It is just an example, I am pulling string format and values from API. Then I am splitting it to array as I need all values separate in different variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the input, I expect you want to create a `string[]` as result rather than a string. To do that, you can use Linq:

```
var s = new[] {"{0}", "hit", "{1}"};
var values = new [] {"Player", "Enemy"};

var result = s.Select((a)=>string.Format(a, values)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it something like:

```
var s = new[] {"{0}", "hit", "{1}"};
var values = new [] {"Player", "Enemy"};

var result = String.Format(String.Join(" ", s), values);
```

Output:

```
Player hit Enemy
```

Comment: Not the output OP expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] a = {"{0}", "hit", "{1}"};
string[] b = {"Player", "Enemy"};
var result = string.Format(string.Join(" ", a), b);
```

should work quite well.